# Serving Unity3D game through web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unity-game-engine, web

I've been assigned the task to serve a Unity3d game in my website (designed by someone else). They're flexible on serving the game directly from the website as they don't know if it
s possible, so in the case that due to X issues it can't be possible I could provide a link (download a player?) to play the game externally. I've been digging through the Unity docs and found out the Unity Webplayer is only compatible with Opera, Safari and older versions of Firefox/I. Usually I'd dig into the matter and come up with a solution eventually but due to the time constraint I feel hard pressed to ask for advice from people who have already jumped these hoops.

Is there an alternative to the Unity Webplayer, does Unity provide some sort of quick, lightweight install for the game to which I can point users to from the website?

I should add that the game will be a lightweight, resource-inexpensive game.

I'm open to any and all suggestions however creative!

The app will most probably use the Rails framework for the web app.

Comment: are you trying to play the game through a browser, or just download the game file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unity's Webplayer has been discontinued in 5.4 release.

> Is there an alternative to the Unity Webplayer, does Unity provide
>   some sort of quick, lightweight install for the game to which I can
>   point users to from the website?

Yes. WebGL. This replaced Webplayer. WebGL is the standard now and works on almost all browsers without the need for players to install anything else. Make sure to download he latest version of Unity to use WebGL 2.0. You can build and embed it on any webpage. Although, Javascript is more easier to use to embed it on the web than ruby.

[image]